# How should I join a field in a table that has been used as a FK in another table in 2 different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in my employee table labeled "employee id"; please see the screenshot. This field is used in another table (products) 2 times as "Builder" , and "Validator". Both of these fields have data type of int. Now, instead of seeing int values for builder, and validator in product table, I want to see the EMPFullname. Also, some of the products may not have any values for builder and validatoer field. Here is the syntaxt that I have:

```
select t1.builder,
t1.validator 
from products as t1 left join employee as emp 
on t1.builder=emp.employeeID
```

But this only gives me the employeeid not full name.How can I have somethig like this:

```
Product_name, builder, Validator,
1234, Jon Snow, Tyran Lannister
```

[image]

Comment: You join twice to Employee - once for the builder information and once for the validator information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use two joins:

```
select p.*, eb.empfullname as builder_fullname, ev.empfullname as validator_fullname
from products p left join
     employee eb
     on p.builder = eb.employeeID left join
     employee ev
     on p.validator = ev.employeeID
```